# mobileconfig file and safari

Tags: iphone

I've created a mobileconfig file and deployed it to webstore. To install mobileconfig file on iPhone i need to either send it in a mail or user can type webstore URL on iphone safari to install it. But my question here is: Will it be possible to create a webview interface or something else and install mobileconfig file silently on the phone? I am asking this because i already have an app where i would like to integrate this rather ask user to go to a URL and install the file. Will it be possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your use case for installing another .mobileconfig file?  The only applications I've seen for this are in overriding phone carrier settings (such as enabling tethering or SMS), which might breach your users' contracts.

Comment: @iamMobile any answers?

Answer (score 9):

I'd be concerned if there was no user consent when installing a mobileconfig file - sounds like a very bad idea incase someone where to implant some rogue settings.

Its good that a user can inspect what the mobileconfig file does before they accept it.

--

dp